# Javascript, reading variable from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, icons

I am having some trouble with showing my custom marker on the map, to show different markers for each location I take the image from the array that also contains the location, for example, here is my code:

```
var examplearray = [
    [43,    52.81421,   5.935412, 'image3']
    ];

    var image1 = 'mapsicons/alpha.png';
    var image2 = 'mapsicons/beta.png';
    var image3 = 'mapsicons/charlie.png';


    for (var i = 0; i < examplearray.length; i++) {
        var samplemarker = examplearray [i]
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng (samplemarker[1], samplemarker[2]),
            map: map,
            icon: samplemarker[3],
            zIndex: samplemarker[0]
        });
    }
```

I cant see whats going wrong here but it doesn't show the images, just to be clear, the images are on the right location and they do work, if I change the "samplemarker[3]" to for example, image1 the icon does show correctly, same goes for changing the "image3" from the array into the image location (mapsicons/charlie.png), it seems that the translation from array data to variable data doesn't work. I hope you can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two other options:

1. to add the URL of the icon to the array.  Instead of:

   var examplearray = [
     [43,    52.81421,   5.935412, 'image3']
   ];

Use:

```
var examplearray = [
  [43,    52.81421,   5.935412, 'mapsicons/charlie.png']
];
```

[Proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nepnyypo/)

2. reference the variable in the array rather than using a string with its name:

Instead of:

```
var examplearray = [
  [43,    52.81421,   5.935412, 'image3']
];
```

Use:

```
var examplearray = [
  [43,    52.81421,   5.935412, image3]
];
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nepnyypo/1/)

**code snippet (option 1):**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var examplearray = [
    [43, 52.81421, 5.935412, 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow.png']
  ];

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < examplearray.length; i++) {
    var samplemarker = examplearray[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(samplemarker[1], samplemarker[2]),
      map: map,
      icon: samplemarker[3],
      zIndex: samplemarker[0]
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

**code snippet (option 2):**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var image1 = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png';
  var image2 = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png';
  var image3 = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow.png';
  var examplearray = [
    [43, 52.81421, 5.935412, image3]
  ];

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < examplearray.length; i++) {
    var samplemarker = examplearray[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(samplemarker[1], samplemarker[2]),
      map: map,
      icon: samplemarker[3],
      zIndex: samplemarker[0]
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me some time to understand the idea. What happens if you replace `icon: samplemarker[3]` with `icon: this[samplemarker[3]]` ?

Comment: When using [samplemarker[3]] it seems to skip the whole icon function and just show the standard markers.